# Windows 7: Monitor start up tasks

Tags: windows-7

Lately my computer has become really slow when starting up. The boot up is fine, but when I enter Windows 7 it's really slow! How can I monitor my start up applications and services so that I can see which task is slow?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Autoruns.

[image]

> This utility, which has the most comprehensive knowledge of
>   auto-starting locations of any startup monitor, shows you what
>   programs are configured to run during system bootup or login, and
>   shows you the entries in the order Windows processes them. These
>   programs include ones in your startup folder, Run, RunOnce, and other
>   Registry keys. You can configure Autoruns to show other locations,
>   including Explorer shell extensions, toolbars, browser helper objects,
>   Winlogon notifications, auto-start services, and much more. Autoruns
>   goes way beyond the MSConfig utility bundled with Windows Me and XP.
>   Autoruns' Hide Signed Microsoft Entries option helps you to zoom in on
>   third-party auto-starting images that have been added to your system
>   and it has support for looking at the auto-starting images configured
>   for other accounts configured on a system. Also included in the
>   download package is a command-line equivalent that can output in CSV
>   format, Autorunsc. You'll probably be surprised at how many
>   executables are launched automatically!

[source](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-PT/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)

I have used this utility in the past and found it very comprehensive and effective.

Answer (score 0):

Within your start menu search for `msconfig`. When you open msconfig, click on the `Startup` tab and check which applications run on startup. Disable any unnecessary startup items and restart your computer. If your computer continues to run slow, disable the remainder of the items one by one until the issue has been resolved. This way you'll be able to determine the cause of the slow down.

Comment: What about services that automatically start up?

Comment: msconfig displays all the programs that automatically startup. If you disable them in there they won't run when your computer starts up.